# Javascript - Can't get the CSS classes to change when calling a function that changes object values

Tags: javascript, css, object

I'm a bit stuck on a side project that I'm working on and I'm getting absolutely nowhere. The project consists of 4 files (1 HTML, 1 CSS, 2 JS files). The majority of the page content is being loaded from a function within "index.js", where the data is being imported from "data.js". The intended outcome is for the "unread" class to be removed when the "read" object property is switched to "true". It's not happening and I suspect that it has something to do with the DOM being loaded and not recognizing/reloading the page content. Here are the files I'm working with (the top one is just the data file, an array of objects):

```
/* I have created a small "mock database" which is just an array of objects containing all of the user data for the challenge. I chose to structure the page content this way to better emulate how something like this would function in a production environment. */

export const mockDatabase = [
  {
    user: "Mark Webber",
    action: "reacted to your recent post",
    containsURL: "My first tournament today!",
    timing: "1m ago",
    isOnline: true,
    avatarImage: "./assets/images/avatar-mark-webber.webp",
    read: false,
    userMessage: "",
  },
  {
    user: "Angela Gray",
    action: "followed you",
    containsURL: "",
    timing: "5m ago",
    isOnline: true,
    avatarImage: "./assets/images/avatar-angela-gray.webp",
    read: false,
    userMessage: "",
  },
  {
    user: "Jacob Thompson",
    action: "has joined your group",
    containsURL: "Chess Club",
    timing: "1 day ago",
    isOnline: true,
    avatarImage: "./assets/images/avatar-jacob-thompson.webp",
    read: false,
    userMessage: "",
  },
  {
    user: "Rizky Hasanuddin",
    action: "sent you a private message",
    containsURL: "",
    timing: "5 days ago",
    isOnline: false,
    avatarImage: "./assets/images/avatar-rizky-hasanuddin.webp",
    read: true,
    userMessage:
      "Hello, thanks for setting up the Chess Club. I've been a member for a few weeks now and I'm already having lots of fun and improving my game.",
  },
  {
    user: "Kimberly Smith",
    action: "commented on your picture",
    containsURL: "",
    timing: "1 week ago",
    isOnline: false,
    avatarImage: "./assets/images/avatar-kimberly-smith.webp",
    read: true,
    userMessage: "./assets/images/image-chess.webp",
  },
  {
    user: "Nathan Peterson",
    action: "reacted to your recent post ",
    containsURL: "5 end-game strategies to increase your win rate",
    timing: "2 weeks ago",
    isOnline: false,
    avatarImage: "./assets/images/avatar-nathan-peterson.webp",
    read: true,
    userMessage: "",
  },
  {
    user: "Anna Kim",
    action: "left the group Chess Club",
    containsURL: "Chess Club",
    timing: "2 weeks ago",
    isOnline: false,
    avatarImage: "./assets/images/avatar-anna-kim.webp",
    read: true,
    userMessage: "",
  },
];
```

This one is where most of the page content rendering takes place:

```
import { mockDatabase } from "./data.js";

/* Listening for the "DOMContentLoaded" event and integrating both the DOM  selector and the event listener function to ensure that the event fires properly */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const changeReadStatus = document.querySelector(
    ".container__header--markread"
  );

  changeReadStatus.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    changeNotificationStatus(mockDatabase);
  });
});

// DOM Elements
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

/* This is the main function that renders the contents of the "mockDatabase" array to the DOM (stored in data.js). It is simply an array of objects containing all of the posts specified within the challenge. */
const renderItems = (item) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    container.innerHTML += `
        <div class="notification__container + ${
          !item[i].read ? "unread" : "read"
        }">
        <img src=${
          item[i].avatarImage
        } class="notification__container--avatar" alt="Image of " ${
      item[i].user
    } />
            <div class="notification__container--group">
           
                <p><span class="user">${item[i].user}</span> ${
      item[i].action
    } <a href="#">${item[i].containsURL}</a><span class=${
      item[i].isOnline ? "online" : ""
    }></span></p>
                <p>${item[i].timing}</p>
                <div class="notification__container--message">
                ${renderContent(item[i])}
                
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
  }
};

/* This function checks all of the postings for messages or images, which are also stored in the userMessage portion of the object. If the userMessage entry is not blank and does not contain an image, the function will render the message content to the page. If it does contain an image, it will be displayed on the page. */
const renderContent = (itemToRender) => {
  if (
    itemToRender.userMessage.trim() !== "" &&
    !itemToRender.userMessage.includes("./assets/images")
  ) {
    return `<p class="usermessage__box">${itemToRender.userMessage}</p>`;
  } else if (itemToRender.userMessage.includes("./assets/images")) {
    return `<img src=${itemToRender.userMessage} alt="some text here" class="message__image" />`;
  } else {
    return "";
  }
};

/* Function that changes the status of all notifications to "read" */
const changeNotificationStatus = (item) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    if (!item[i].read) {
      item[i].read = true;
    }
  }
};

renderItems(mockDatabase);
```

This line here should ideally render/remove the "unread" class and change the div color from blue to white once the property is reset by the changeNotificationStatus function. I can see that the values are changing, but the classes aren't being modified:

```
<div class="notification__container + ${
          !item[i].read ? "unread" : "read"
        }">
```

I appreciate you taking the time to read this. If possible, please point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong. Once I get this fixed, I can complete and publish...thanks!!!

I've attempted to call the "renderItems" function on the "mockDatabase" function again, which wasn't successful. I've subsequently tried to move the "renderItems" function and nest it within the "DOMContentLoaded" event listener function, which was also unsuccessful. I'm stuck and can't move forward.

Comment: When you create the DIV, it checks the `read` property at that time. It doesn't create a permanent link between the object and the DIV. Your code that changes the property needs to update the class list.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried a few different approaches and couldn't get them to work, so I'll come back to it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the property has been changed from `unread` to `read` whenever the `click` event happens. But like @Barmar mentioned in the comment, even though the property has been changed in the data, it won't reflect in the UI as there is no such link between data and DOM elements. You have to do that yourself after the property changes event is completed.

**Possible Solutions:**
Maybe you can call the `renderItems` function again by emptying the container element first. But this will recreate the whole div elements. There could be other performant way

Comment: Thanks! This is getting super complicated unfortunately :(. I've tried calling renderItems again and it didn't work. I think I might have to keep on looking for possible ways to solve this...just difficult to do with vanilla JS and CSS. I'm going to take a break from it and try again tomorrow.

Comment: After the function `changeNotificationStatus(mockDatabase)` inside the event register,

Do this
    
    1. Make the container inner HTML to be the empty string and 
    2. Recall the function `renderItems(mockDatabase)`


This should work easily. I have tested it